# Hyperledger Fabric Network config from scratch

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to understand Hyperledger Fabric Network configurations.

I read the doc and tried to understand the samples but it's a lot of files and I couldn't find anywhere which files are to use to set up a network from scratch asides from the test-network samples provided.

My questions are:

- where do I have to write my organizations, channels, CAs?
- which are the minimum config for starting a network?
- where's the list of the parameters available of these config files such as peers attributes etc?

Hoping to find clarity in your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow "[**Building Your First Network**](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html#want-to-run-it-now)" tutorial. There is a **byfn.sh** file where you can find all the necessary steps. You can also do everything with manual commands which is also written on later section of "[**Building Your First Network**](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html#want-to-run-it-now)" tutorial.